# WPF comboboxes only allowing integers as text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have about 10 combo boxes. They are all populated with table adapters using a .xsd file.
I'm using Linq to SQL to grab a specific row and default the combo boxes to certain columns of that row. Here is my combo box code

```
                cmbCompany.Text = query.intAcctCo.ToString();
                cmbCompanyRec.Text = query.intAcctCoRec.ToString();
                cmbProgramCodes.Text = query.chrPgmCode;
                cmbCarrierCodes.Text = query.intCarrierCode.ToString();
                cmbDealerNumber.Text = query.chrDlrNum;
                cmbCoverageCodes.Text = query.chrCvgCode;
                cmbPayeeType.Text = query.chrPayeeType;
                cmbFeeType.Text = query.chrFeeType;
                cmbPayeeCodes.Text = query.intPayeeCode.ToString();
                cmbTransactionTypes.Text = query.chrTransType;
```

Here is the query

```
   var query =
                (from z in dc.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts2
                 where z.intActgAcctID == unique
                 select z).FirstOrDefault();
```

"unique" is just an identifier for the specific row

All of the ones with "ToString()" are working correctly the other are not. I have tried multiple things with no luck. It even shows that they have the value needed as text when i hover over in debug mode, but when the page loads, they are blank. I've tried adding "ToString()" to the others even though they are already strings and no luck. Ideas?

I'm on visual studio 2013, .net framework of 4.5.1. All of the xaml for the combo boxes is the same.

Comment: it totally depends on the datasource you are binding to your combobox and field value of the datasource you are binding to combobox.. please show  us the xaml code so we can help you.

Comment: Ashok is correct. If your `ComboBox` won't have those elements in the list then every time it will show blank if you will try to set Text property. Is your `ComboBox` editable? Share your `XAML` with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to structure your data correctly. You said:

> I'm using Linq to SQL to grab a specific row

Put that row data into a custom class, that has a `public` property for each column and then [data bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) it to your `ComboBox`es. You could then add extra properties to reflect the selected item in each `ComboBox` and data bind those to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` properties of each `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollectionProperty}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedItemProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Then , when you want to select an item from code, you can just do this:

```
YourSelectedItemProperty = YourCollectionProperty.FirstOrDefault();
```

Or this:

```
YourSelectedItemProperty = YourCollectionProperty.ElementAt(10);
```

I suggest that you have a good, long read of the linked data binding page on MSDN.